# Fatal pylint error when using with Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, pylint

This error appears whenever I save a file. Please help guys.

I use Pylinter and SublimeLinter.

```
Fatal pylint error:
/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
```

Here is the screenshot :

[image]

Comment: which pylint plugin are you using?

Comment: @MattDMo I use Pylinter with SublimeLinter sir.

Comment: How did you install `pylint` on your system?

Comment: I reinstalled everthing and it works perfectly sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question like you.After check on the internet, I found you need install pylint in python first.(Os windows ,python 3.5,sunlime text 3)

1. Press "windows+R",type "cmd" enter the command model then type "pip install pylint" to install pylint.
2. Open sublime, install pylint package on sublime.

The problem should be solved by this.

Comment: Please considering reformatting this to make it clearer.